QUOTA_BYTES_PER_ITEM: quota exceeded
I am fetching data from my custom backend hosted in Golang to a react+typescript frontend hosted on vercel. I get this QUOTA exceeded error.
type Event struct {
    Event_ID       primitive.ObjectID     `json:"_Eid,omitempty" bson:"_id,omitempty"`
    Soc_ID         primitive.ObjectID     `json:"_Sid" bson:"_sid"`
    User_ID        primitive.ObjectID     `json:"_Uid" bson:"_uid"`
    Soc_Email      string                 `json:"email" bson:"email"`
    Soc_Name       string                 `json:"soc_name" bson:"soc_name"`
    Title          string                 `json:"title" bson:"title"`
    Description    string                 `json:"description,omitempty" bson:"description,omitempty"`
    CreatedAt      int64                  `json:"createdAt" bson:"createdAt"`
    StartDate      int64                  `json:"start_date,omitempty" bson:"start_date,omitempty"`
    EndDate        int64                  `json:"end_date,omitempty" bson:"end_date,omitempty"`
    Visibility     bool                   `json:"visibility" bson:"visibility"`
    Team           bool                   `json:"team" bson:"team"`
    MaxTeamMembers int                    `json:"max_team_members,omitempty" bson:"max_team_members,omitempty"`
    MinTeamMembers int                    `json:"min_team_members,omitempty" bson:"min_team_members,omitempty"`
    Additional     map[string]interface{} `json:"additional,omitempty" bson:"additional,omitempty"`
    Parameters     map[string]interface{} `json:"parameters,omitempty" bson:"parameters,omitempty"`
    EventType      string                 `json:"event_type,omitempty" bson:"event_type,omitempty"`
    EventMode      string                 `json:"event_mode,omitempty" bson:"event_mode,omitempty"`
    Hashtags       []string               `json:"hashtags,omitempty" bson:"hashtags,omitempty"`
    SocialMedia    map[string]interface{} `json:"social_media,omitempty" bson:"social_media,omitempty"`
    Prizes         map[string]interface{} `json:"prizes,omitempty" bson:"prizes,omitempty"`
    Eligibility    string                 `json:"eligibility,omitempty" bson:"eligibility,omitempty"`
    PhotoGallery   []string               `json:"photo_gallery,omitempty" bson:"photo_gallery,omitempty"`
    Venue          string                 `json:"venue,omitempty" bson:"venue,omitempty"`
    Image          string                 `json:"image" bson:"image"`
}


This is the amount of data and also in terms of lsit will be fetched in the call.
How can I resolve this error
I tried getting a success response ans this didn't go as I planned.

Do the answers to this question help? Unfortunately your question does not provide sufficient detail (e.g. payload size, where does the error occur, MRE etc) so it's difficult to provide more of an answer.
